# ReactJS - Babel version problems

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/1.0.0/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
            document.getElementById('container')
        );
    </script>
</body>
```

babel 5.8.23 use script no error

but babel 6.1.19 use script error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

why error 6.1.19 yet upgrade

I know the cause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The babel-browser package has now been removed and new versions of it won't be released. There's no use case for it in Babel 6.

check this [babel 6](https://github.com/babel/babel/commit/c0afdfd1a83aab0c25a1fc23cee0b09d560f4d35)

Comment: what does that mean practically. Should I just keep using V5 then?